# How can I rewrite this query without sub-queries?

Tags: sql

So what I want to do:

I have a table that has some prices of some items of a store, what I want to do is to find the average price of all the items sold from that store, AND the sum of all similar items sold in store.

My columns are:

- item_no
- branch
- totalamount

What is really important is that I have to avoid sub-queries so I couldn't do something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT branch AS postcode, item_no, avg_price
FROM Prices 
NATURAL JOIN (SELECT branch, AVG(totalamount) avg_price FROM Prices GROUP BY branch) av
WHERE  sum  > avg_price ORDER BY turnover DESC , branch;
```

Which does exactly what I want to do, nevertheless I have to do it without sub-queries.

edit 1 QUESTION:

IS THERE A DIFFERENCE between derived and temporary tables? so for the assignment , i am not allowed to use subqueries, OR temporary tables, so does my answer have any of those 2?

Comment: For the per-branch average price you can use a self-join and GROUP BY instead of a subquery. But it's not clear to me what the rest is doing... what relation do item_no and avg_turnover have to branches? What's the primary key? Can we see the schema?

Comment: @Sam...Just of Note: What you are using are called Derived tables.  Sub queries are Select statements as part of the where or Column.  Think of Derived tables as selecting from a non-indexed view.

Comment: For what database?  Though it's likely MySQL...

Answer (score 0):

You can specify multiple aggregate statements on the same or different columns within the same SELECT statement. To see exactly what I mean have a look in books online.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177677.aspx

Comment: This has "homework" written all over it. You could do it with temp tables (or temp variables in sql server), but it would be more efficient with one sql statement that uses subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

here how you can do it,

```
SELECT branch AS postcode, 
       item_no, 
       AVG(totalamount) avg_price , 
       SUM(totalamount) sum
FROM prices
WHERE  SUM(totalamount) > avg_turnover 
ORDER BY avg_turnover DESC , 
         eatit_Order.branch
GROUP BY branch, 
         item_no;
```

Comment: Then tell us with sample data how the result should look.