# Does this query use any sub-queries or temporary tables?

Tags: sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I rewrite this query without sub-queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160857/how-can-i-rewrite-this-query-without-sub-queries)

I am not allowed to use sub-queries or any kind of temporary tables as a part of an answer, does this query use any of those?

```
SELECT DISTINCT  item_no, avg_price
FROM Prices 
NATURAL JOIN (SELECT  AVG(totalamount) avg_price FROM Prices GROUP BY price) av
WHERE  sum  > aurnover ORDER BY avg_price DESC , branch;
```

Comment: Are you trying to trick us into helping you with your homework? You might want to look up what a subquery is and how to figure out if your query is using temporary tables. I'll teach you how to fish. Look up the `EXPLAIN` keyword.

Comment: Your were receiving help in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160857/how-can-i-rewrite-this-query-without-sub-queries), please don't create duplicates.

Comment: Google or WIKI "what is a sub query in sql"...and the answer will climb out of the computer, smack you, then tell you...I am right here...did you not see me.uuh...us?

Comment: check my response to your previous question.

Comment: You could use a Common Table Expression (CTE), then? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are using two sub-queries on these lines:

```
NATURAL JOIN (SELECT branch, AVG(totalamount) avg_price FROM Prices GROUP BY branch) av
NATURAL JOIN (SELECT item_no,branch, SUM(totalamount) sum FROM Prices GROUP BY branch, table_no) su
```

Comment: ..these are not subqueries these are derived tables...there is a difference

Comment: @John Hartstock: a derived table is defined using a subquery construct. One could say, informally, that 'derived table' is a subtype of 'subquery'. If you want a formal definition, see the SQL-92 spec: section 6.3 'table reference': 'derived table' ::= 'table subquery'.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've definitely got subqueries (you can see that clearly with the nested SELECT calls).

You'd likely need to inspect the output of EXPLAIN-ing that (just append EXPLAIN to the start of that query for your database) to know for sure if it'll generate a temporary table. Look for the text "using temporary" in the "Extra" column.

Answer (score 0):

What you have are derived tables.

A derived table is similar to selecting from a view

Consider this:

```
SELECT
  * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLEA) A
```

If you made a the table you are selecting from the outside is derived from the inner select
Note as a derived table the select will only run once

This is an example of a sub query which will run once for every tableA Record

```
Select
  (Select ID from TABLEB WHERE tableB.Code = TableA.Code) AS TableBID
FROM TableA
```

This is also a subquery

```
   Select 
     *
   FROM TableA
   Where TableA.Code IN (Select TABLEB.Code From TableB)
```

Subquerys are generally used in Where Clauses and Columns but can cause serious preformance issues.

Comment: A derived table is also a subquery. One could say, informally, that 'derived table' is a subtype of 'subquery'. If you want a formal definition, see the SQL-92 spec: section 6.3 'table reference': 'derived table' ::= 'table subquery'